# How to implement sharedPreferences in a Fragment in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to save data from my fragment in Kotlin, I tried to use shared preference for that since I'm only saving strings in the fragment. I don't understand why the data is not saving. I'm using them both in OnViewCreated.

First Fragment IMAGE [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqlUt.png
Second Fragment Image [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifpRU.png

FirstFragment

```
        val sharedPreferences =
            requireActivity().applicationContext.getSharedPreferences("sharedPref",Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val price = sharedPreferences.getString("PRICE",null)
        binding.priceId.text = price
        val expense = sharedPreferences.getString("EXPENSE",null)
        binding.priceId1.text = expense
```

Second Fragment with EditText

```
        val insertedText : String = binding.itemPrice.text.toString()
        val insertedText2 : String = binding.itemPrice2.text.toString()        
   val sharedPreferences = requireActivity().applicationContext.getSharedPreferences("sharedPref",Context.MODE_PRIVATE)       
  
        val editor : SharedPreferences.Editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
        editor.apply {
            putString("PRICE",insertedText)
            putString("EXPENSE",insertedText2)
        }
        editor.apply()
        Toast.makeText(requireContext(),"Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
```

Comment: How you know that the data is not saving? Did you look into `sharedPref` file and it is empty?

Comment: use commit() instead of apply()

Comment: Yeah the sharedPref file shows the value.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'm using sharedPreferences with fragment

```
//Getting the sharedPreferences    
val appContext = requireContext().applicationContext
        var prefs = appContext.getSharedPreferences("sharedPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

prefs.edit().putString("PRICE", insertedText).apply();
```

Comment: i did the exact same thing i think , if u notice

Comment: I'm not familiar with the syntax you used. Sorry for that. You are using requireActivity, I'm using requireContext.

Apart from that obvious question, but have you checked if the variable "insertedText" contains data ?