# How do I use shared preferences when a button is clicked

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, sharedpreferences

I am working on an Android app using Android Studio.
I want to save the values input into some editText textFields.
These textFields are in a Fragment view? (sorry I am very new to Android coding).
I have tried to use SharedPreferences but keep getting the error.
(Unresolved reference: getSharedPreference).

Here is my code:

```
import android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE
import android.content.SharedPreferences
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import androidx.core.os.bundleOf
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController


class ConnectFragment : Fragment() {

override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_connect, container, false)
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    
    view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.button_connect).setOnClickListener {
        val serverURIFromEditText =
            view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.edittext_server_uri).text.toString()
        val clientIDFromEditText =
            view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.edittext_client_id).text.toString()
        val usernameFromEditText =
            view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.edittext_username).text.toString()
        val pwdFromEditText =
            view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.edittext_password).text.toString()

        val mqttCredentialsBundle = bundleOf(
            MQTT_SERVER_URI_KEY to serverURIFromEditText,
            MQTT_CLIENT_ID_KEY to clientIDFromEditText,
            MQTT_USERNAME_KEY to usernameFromEditText,
            MQTT_PWD_KEY to pwdFromEditText
        )

        findNavController().navigate(
            R.id.action_ConnectFragment_to_ClientFragment,
            mqttCredentialsBundle
        )

val sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences =
            getSharedPreferences("MyFacts", MODE_PRIVATE)
        val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
        editor.putString("UserName", usernameFromEditText)
        editor.apply()
    }
  }
}
```

Not sure what is up except to think that it is not in the MainActivity view but in a Fragment.  But can't figure out how to resolve it.  Could someone help me.

Comment: Need to go through the activity so try: `activity?.getSharedPreferences(...)`  .  Or this alternative: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70575588/17856705 .

Comment: Use `requireActivity.getSharedPreferences(...)` in a Fragment.